# What is the cUrl command to get open and click details of an email sent through Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-ses

I can send email using cUrl in Amazon SES. I get the test email.
But when I tried "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com?Action=GetSendStatistics" to track the status, response is vague.

```
<GetSendStatisticsResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
    <GetSendStatisticsResult>
        <SendDataPoints>
            <member>
                <Rejects>0</Rejects>
                <Complaints>0</Complaints>
                <Bounces>0</Bounces>
                <DeliveryAttempts>1</DeliveryAttempts>
                <Timestamp>2023-05-15T08:08:00Z</Timestamp>
            </member>
            <member>
                <Rejects>0</Rejects>
                <Complaints>0</Complaints>
                <Bounces>0</Bounces>
                <DeliveryAttempts>2</DeliveryAttempts>
                <Timestamp>2023-05-15T07:53:00Z</Timestamp>
            </member>
            <member>
                <Rejects>0</Rejects>
                <Complaints>0</Complaints>
                <Bounces>0</Bounces>
                <DeliveryAttempts>3</DeliveryAttempts>
                <Timestamp>2023-05-15T14:53:00Z</Timestamp>
            </member>
        </SendDataPoints>
    </GetSendStatisticsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>1a7fab12-7428-48fb-83eb-2af3eb3995d4</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</GetSendStatisticsResponse>
```

What is the cUrl command to get open and click details? There is no clear documentation in API reference.

Comment: With Amazon SES `GetSendStatistics` API operation, you can only monitor these events -  Deliveries, bounces, complaints, and rejects. To monitor Opens and Clicks, you can use Cloudwatch. For more details read :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity.html